# Optimize Webpack React Babel - Does it make sense to include only selected plugins for Babel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

This question has two parts:

1.

Is there anything I can do in webpack config file to make my .js file even more compressed? Currently it is 984 kB.

I noticed that adding following plugins, doesn't change anything.

Are they included properly?

```
plugins: [
    'transform-react-remove-prop-types',
    'transform-react-constant-elements',
    'transform-react-inline-elements'
]
```

My production config file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path')
const nodeModulesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: './js/app/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/js'),
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    cache: false,
    debug: false,
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compressor: {
                warnings: false
            }
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            components: path.resolve(__dirname, './js/components/'),
            app: path.resolve(__dirname, './js/app/'),
            Auth: path.resolve(__dirname, './js/features/Auth/'),
            DataDisplay: path.resolve(__dirname, './js/features/DataDisplay/'),
            Forms: path.resolve(__dirname, './js/features/Forms/'),
        },
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.es6', '.json'],
    },
    stats: {
        colors: true,
        reasons: true,
        chunks: false
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.(jsx|js|es6)?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: [nodeModulesPath],
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
                plugins: ['transform-react-remove-prop-types',
                    'transform-react-constant-elements',
                    'transform-react-inline-elements'
                ]
            }
        }, {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json-loader'
        }]
    }
}
```

2. Second question is regarding babel, currently I am using just following ES2015 preset:

   {
         "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
       }

However during "Complete Introduction to React (feat. Redux and React Router)" on Frontend Masters, Brian Holt pointed out that this preset contains a lot of stuff which is not really needed. Does it make sense to include only plugins I know I used?

For example I know I haven't used transform-regenerator (which according to him is a specially big) or transform-es2015-classes. And if it makes sense what is the easiest way to configure babel, without installing all of them separately...

Comment: Babel plugins don't go in the root of your Webpack config - they should be in the same place as the presets (whether they're in the config file or a `.babelrc` file). That'll be why they're having no effect!

Comment: In other words, what you specified in your second question should be expanded to `{ "presets": ["react", "es2015"], "plugins": [ .. ] }`

Comment: @JoeClay is it possible to use different .babelrc file base on which build I am running? Clearly would be nice to use transform-react-remove-prop-types only in production.

Comment: Since you already have separate Webpack configs for each build, it'd probably be easiest to just put your Babel options in those. [See the `query` property in the usage section of the loader docs](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#usage) - that can be used in place of a `.babelrc` file.

Comment: I updated my config file accordingly, however still there is no change... Maybe my code is not big enough to make a difference...

Comment: Well, the first thing I'd check is whether or not the Babel plugins are having an effect - do a diff/manual comparison of your output file with them on and off. Your config *looks* fine to me, but it's still probably worth making sure!

Comment: Also, maybe you can just hack the [`.babelrc` file's environment key](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/) for different plugins, and just set the `BABEL_ENV` for the different settings